# Prevent webpack from rebuilding unless sources have changed

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I use webpack as a bundler AND task runner.

I don't want it to rebuild bundles if sources haven't changed:

- when run in watch mode, it caches to memory, and won't rebuild unless necessary
- BUT as a pure task runner (no watch mode), it **rebuilds on every run**

How do I prevent it from rebuilding every time? It takes longer, and thrashes my SSD drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the answer](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/other-options/#cachetype):

```js
cache: {
  type: 'filesystem',
},
```

But sometimes I use webpack in watch mode, so I want to use `memory` instead. So I did this:

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) {

  // ...

  cache: function () {
    return argv.env.WEBPACK_WATCH ? { type: 'memory' } : { type: 'filesystem' };
  }(),

}
```

So when in watch mode it will use memory, and when used as a pure task runner (not watching) it will cache to disk.

And in both cases webpack will avoid rebuilding if source files haven't changed.